# How to get static fields from another class using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, static

We have a static class called `VisualizationSettings` that has ~20 instances of a struct we made called `VisualizationSetting` (singular).

I want to have another class pull in all the individual instances of `VisualizationSetting` from `VisualizationSettings`, and modify them.

I added a method to `VisualizationSettings` that should get and return all instances of `VisualizationSetting`, like so:

```
    public static FieldInfo[] GetFields(){
        Type myType = typeof(VisualizationSetting);
        FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();
        return myField;
    }
```

Then, in my other class, I access this `FieldInfo[]`, iterate through it, and modify it, like so:

```
    FieldInfo[] myField = VisualizationSettings.GetFields();

    foreach (FieldInfo setting in myField) {
        VisualizationSetting value = (VisualizationSetting)setting.GetValue(null);

        /* A bunch of stuff to modify value */

        setting.SetValue(null, value);
    }
```

However I get an error on the line `VisualizationSetting value = (VisualizationSetting)setting.GetValue(null);` saying `TargetException: Non-static field requires a target`

My confusion is that as far as I'm aware, setting should static, since `VisualizationSettings` is a static class.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: `VisualizationSettings` is static, but you are trying to get the fields of `VisualizationSetting`

Comment: Your code is: `Type myType = typeof(VisualizationSetting);` then `FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();` then `(VisualizationSetting)setting.GetValue(null);` where `setting` is one of `myField`, so, like @OfirWinegarten says, you are trying to get instance values.

Comment: But we declare the `VisualizationSetting` instances as `public static VisualizationSetting` within the `VisualizationSettings` class, so those should be static, no?  I want to modify those static values, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the fields from the wrong class.
You should iterate through the fields of `VisualizationSettings` not `VisualizationSetting`.

```
public static FieldInfo[] GetFields(){
    Type myType = typeof(VisualizationSettings); // <-- the change is here
    FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();
    return myField;
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did it!  In order to make sure I only modified the `VisualizationSetting` fields (which was all that I was interested in) I added a `if (setting.FieldType == typeof(VisualizationSetting))` check to my iteration loop and it worked flawlessly.  Thanks!